# grep blank fields in Linux

Tags: linux, unix

I am having a file with 1000 lines and each line with 170 fields. I want to grep a particular field; for example, field number 30 is blank or not....

Comment: Paste a section of the file (or it's expected format here). The trick is in always identifying what structure (or lack of) that can be exploited in the data.

Comment: You can use [awk](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/19331-awk-how-check-if-field-blank.html) for this.

Comment: Please try to paste some code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

if the field separator is "`:`"

```
awk -F":" '{if($30=="")print $0}' file_name
```

This above command will print the lines whose field 30 is blank.

Comment: I tried this but not coming,  awk -F "," '{if($20="")print $0}'

Comment: Or even just `awk -F: '$30==""' file_name`

Comment: The answer had a typo; I fixed it.  Try again, please?

Comment: Or even just `awk -F: '!$30'`

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention a specific field separator, so I will just go on with a CSV-based example. To `grep` for field 30 being blank using [`GNU grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

```
$ grep -n '^\([^,]*,\)\{29\},' test.csv 
2:2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,55,,33
```

Essentially we require 29 fields with a trailing comma (`,`) separator each and then yet another separator character directly afterwards with no intermediate text.

The presence of the `-n` option ensures that any matches are prefixed with the line number so that you will be able to tell *where* each match is in the input file.

I believe that this would work on any POSIX-compatible grep, but I am not certain.